# Accessing loop functions (e.g the_title or the_content) from post ID

Tags: custom-field, loop

I have an array of post IDs obtained through complicated filtering code. I want to display posts from these IDs, and for each post I need access to regular post functions like the_title and such. More importantly, for each post I need to retrieve custom fields values (and even more precisely I need values of "relationship" fields created with Advanced Custom Fields plugin).

Is there a way to access regular post functions from anywhere simply based on post IDs, just as if I was inside the regular loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [`get_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) to get the [post objects](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post#Member_Variables_of_WP_Post) of a given post.

This will be unfiltered objects, so you would want to make use of `apply_filters` and the appropriate filters described in the linked page.

If you need to get info from a custom field, whether native custom fields of ACF fields, you can simply add the ID to the [`get_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) for native custom fields or `the_field` or `get_field` functions in ACF.

Remember, by default, the post ID of the current post is used, but you can change this to any post ID you wish to get info from